# How can ensure async calls in an event handler in an extension service worker run to completion?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a service worker in my extension which listens for an action:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async function(tab) {
  await performAction();
});
```

According to the docs, the service worker can be stopped at any moment. How can I ensure my `performAction` is not interrupted at some async call?

Comment: Your service worker shouldn't "stop" when it's waiting for an event asynchronously so it shouldn't be necessary to use any equivalent of `waitUntil` - can you post more context?

Comment: There's no such thing in extensions as `event.waitUntil` so what is it and how you use it? What "stuff" exactly do you want to do and why you don't want the worker to be stopped? Since the worker stops after 30 seconds of idle time it all seems pretty weird without more info. Anyway, the only way to keep the worker is to have an open chrome.runtime port to some other page or content script and reconnect each five minutes.

Comment: OK, I see. `waitUntil` is not available for extension service workers, even on `install` events etc. where it is available in web service workers.

Comment: @wOxxOm: thanks for the indications. I've not been able to find any docs describing when the worker is stopped -- the 30 seconds, the trick with the chrome.runtime port... Everything I read indicates it can be stopped at any moment when it is not running. I'll appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Whoever wrote the documentation was using non-technical terms so don't pay attention to it. The numbers and the method I mentioned are taken directly from Chromium source code. More info and source links in https://crbug.com/1146434